# how to add customised Debug Configuration popup in eclipse neon specific to my own plugin project

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, debugging, eclipse-plugin

[Debug Configuration in eclipse sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhhEF.png)

[Debug Configuration of DS-5 plugin in eclipse sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsYXk.png)

I want to create my own customised debug configuration option for my specific plugin project in eclipse like DS-5. In the screenshot shared, I want to achieve debug configuration like DS-5. How can it be achieved in Eclipse Neon?

Comment: This is a very large topic, read everything in the [Program debug and launch support](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdebug.htm) section of the help. You are particularly looking for the Launch Configuration Dialog but you need to understand all of the launch support.

Comment: Thanks greg-449 for the pointer. It worked for me.